# How to send a newline from vb.net to sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net, newline

on c# you could to have your variable

```
string sql =@"create table #order (oldcolumn int)  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#order') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #order
go
create table #order (newcolumn int)
select newcolum from #order

"
```

and when this is execute this work

now on vb.net I do

dim sql as string

```
sql=" create table #order (oldcolumn int) IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#order') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #order " & _
    " go " & _
    " create table #order (newcolumn int) " & _
    " select newcolum from #order "
```

but it doesnt work because go must to have on a new line and the before code
return all the script on a large line..

I have try witn `vbCrLf`, `Environment.NewLine`,`"\r\n"`
but this continue failing.

the real query is similar to before example..
this fail because the column "newcolumn" not exist (yet) on table and I am doing the select to this table.. if you execute the drop table first it does work

Comment: Honestly I'd drop this line altogether and implement this in a t-sql sproc.

Comment: `vbCrLf` and `Environment.NewLine` should both work.  `sql = "mystring" & vbCrLf & "string2"`

Comment: Or use a stringbuilder with `AppendLine("mystring")`

Comment: I used ..."  go " + vbCrLf & _

Comment: `+` does the same thing as `&` in this context.

Comment: @angel Have you tried with begin/end like this `IF() BEGIN -- END`?

Answer (score 1):

The white space is optional in SQL. There is no difference at all between:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
GO
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 GO SELECT * FROM Table2
```

I would suggest looking into the following items in your SQL:

1. The spelling of `newcolum` and `newcolumn` do not match in your `CREATE` and `SELECT` statements.
2. The very first thing you are trying to do is `CREATE TABLE #order`, but it may already exist in the database left from the last time you created it in your `CREATE TABLE #order (newcolumn int)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to upgrade to **Visual Studio 2015**?
**Visual Basic 14** has the same multi-line literals as C# `@"strings"`:

```vb
Dim sql As String = "
    SELECT t1.Name, 
           t1.Description, 
           t1.Address, 
           t1.PhoneNumber, 
           t2.RegistrationID, 
           t2.Date, 
           t2.Description, 
           t2.RegistrationStatus 
    FROM   Users t1 
           JOIN Registrations t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID 
    WHERE   t2.RegistrationID = @RegistrationID
"
```

The only thing you need to escape inside the string is `"` (replace it with `""`).

And great new **string interpolation** feature helps you make your strings readable like never before:

```vb
Dim tableName As String = "Registrations"
Dim currentOrderByColumn As String = "t2.Date"

Dim sql = $"SELECT t1.Name, t1.Description FROM {tableName} ORDER BY {currentOrderByColumn}"

Dim sql2 = $"
    SELECT t1.Name, t1.Description
    FROM {tableName}
    ORDER BY {currentOrderByColumn}
"
```

Expressions inside interpolated strings also fully support variable renaming, so renaming `tableName` to `mainTableName` will also perform renaming inside the string.

More information: [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14.aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

If you cannot upgrade, then use

```vb
Dim sql = <sql>SELECT t1.Name, 
           t1.Description, 
           t1.Address, 
           t1.PhoneNumber, 
           t2.RegistrationID, 
           t2.Date, 
           t2.Description, 
           t2.RegistrationStatus 
    FROM   Users t1 
           JOIN Registrations t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID 
    WHERE   t2.RegistrationID = @RegistrationID</sql>.Value
```

but *I do not recommend this* (I recommend upgrading the VS) because this workaround has now became obsolete and has its caveats. (Think about escaping `<`, `&` and others. If you forget...)

Another workaround is:

```vb
Dim sql = String.Join(vbCrLf,
                      "SELECT ...",
                      "FROM ...",
                      "WHERE ...")
```